# Sending one row of a 2D array to a function in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

I am new to C# and trying to learn how to send individual rows of a 2D array to a function. I have a two-dimensional array of 3 rows and 2 columns. If I want to send my third row to a function called `calculate`, can you please tell me how to do this.

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[,] array2Db = new string[3, 2] { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" }, { "five", "six" } };
            calculate(array2Db[2,0]); //I want to send only the 3rd row to this array
            //This array may contain millions of words. Therefore, I can't pass each array value individually
        }

        void calculate(string[] words)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(words);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the length of the 'Y' dimension (x = 0, y = 1) we create an Enumerable of numbers between 0 and Y's length, which will serve as a loop to iterate and retrieve all the elements where the 'X' dimension = 2 (3rd in a 0-based collection)

```
var yRange = Enumerable.Range(0, array2Db.GetLength(1));
var result = yRange.Select(y => array2Db[2, y]);
```

Or in your case (I changed the parameter received by **calculate()** from string array to IEnumerable to avoid pointless type conversion:

```
calculate(Enumerable.Range(0, array2Db.GetLength(1)).Select(y => array2Db[2, y]));

static void calculate(IEnumerable<string> words)
{
    foreach(string word in words)
        Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

EDIT: tried to add some clarification

Comment: This is a nice example, but compared to the example of the question. This might be hard to grasp.

Comment: @Innat3 thank you for showing with an example. When I run this code, it gives an out put as follows: `System.String[]` 
`System.String[]`

Comment: @DP. ah I found the issue, you are not passing the index value while displaying array elements in the **calculate()** method. I will add an update

Comment: Thank you for showing with details and answering my question the way it was asked.

Answer (score 6):

You could make an extension method that will enumerate you the specific row.

```
public static class ArrayExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GetRow<T>(this T[,] items, int row)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.GetLength(1); i++)
        {
            yield return items[row, i];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it with

```
string[,] array2Db = new string[3, 2] { { "one", "two" }, { "three", "four" }, { "five", "six" } };
calculate(array2Db.GetRow(2).ToArray());
```

Comment: Nice durable answer. +1, You might want to change the `calculate(string[] words)` signature to `calculate(IEnumerable<string> words)` or call it like: `calculate(array2Db.GetRow(2).ToArray());`

Comment: Good point, added the cast to array and dynamic array dimension in the extension.

Answer (score 2):

`array2Db[2, 0]` will give you a single value at the third row first column, which is a  string actually, not an array as the method `calculate` is expecting, If you want to pass the complete row means you have to call the method like the following:

```
calculate(new []{array2Db[2, 0],array2Db[2, 1]});
```

Which will pass the two columns of the third row as an array to the called method. A [working Example here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MckpHk)

Answer (score 0):

I found this looking for an answer to the same problem, but the List collection was easier for me.

```
List<string[]> array2Db = new List<string[]>() { 
        new string[] { "one", "two" }, 
        new string[] { "three", "four" }, 
        new string[] { "five", "six" } 
    };
calculate(array2Db[2]);
```